# artisan command always shows the message Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)

Tags: laravel, git, kubernetes, laravel-artisan

I have an app running with Docker and the .git directory is ignored to reduced the project's size.

The problem is that every time an artisan command is ran this message is displayed and stored inside the logs of Kubernetes. Moreover, in some cases is the reason why some kubernetes tasks cannot reach the HEALTHY status.

I have a Cronjob with kubernetes which reaches just 2/3 and the only message that the logs displayed is this one.

Comment: Was this a cloned project? As a temporary solution you could just create an empty git repo in your Docker container `git init`.

Comment: It's a project with its git repository but the .git folder is ignored by docker, otherwise the docker image would be way too big. git init does not work, the message disappears but another is shown instead

Answer (score 5):

[monicahq/monica PR 950](https://github.com/monicahq/monica/pull/950) is an example of a workaround where the Sentry configuration is modified to test for the presence of the Git repository, ensuring `php artisan config:cache` is run only once.

```
// capture release as git sha
'release' => is_dir(__DIR__.'/../.git') ? trim(exec('git log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')) : null,
```

Comment: @Jorge Great! Don't forget to review this or your past questions and accept the answers you deem accetpable (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/6309). I noticed you have rarely accepted an answer.